# JavaMail API and Tomcat 7 Implementation

Tags: java, api, jakarta-ee, smtp, jakarta-mail

There are several Java EE APIs that exist as just that - APIs (interfaces, domain objects, enums, etc. but no actual classes that *do* stuff). APIs like JPA, JDBC or JTA. These APIs must then have implementations; for JPA there are impls like Hibernate, MyBatis or TopLink. For JDBC there are drivers for each specific RDBMS. For JTA there is Bitronix and Atomikos.

But what about JavaMail? Is it just an API? If so, what are some common implementations of it? If I deploy my Java app (as a WAR) to Tomcat 7, where does this implementation come from (specifically)? Does Tomcat have its own JavaMail impl? What JARs/packages/classes compose the Tomcat impl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaMail is a standard [JSR 919](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=919)

TomEE server has support for JavaMail.

The configuration is very easy and goes like this

1. tomee already comes with `apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0/lib/geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.2.jar`
2. in `tomee.xml` (configured at `$TOMEE/conf`) you add an entry as described by [Configuring JavaMail](http://tomee.apache.org/configuring-javamail.html)
3. from inside your classes you can reference the mail session via `@Resource` like described at [javax.mail.Session resource and smtp authentication](http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/javax-mail-Session-resource-and-smtp-authentication-td4322915.html)

Comment: Thanks @Leo (+1) but I'm interested only in straight Tomcat 7 here, not TomEE (which includes all sorts of other JARs/libs). Can you modify your answers for Tomcat 7? Thanks again!

Comment: sure. for vanilla tomcat, you can follow this http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JavaMail_Sessions

Comment: Thanks again @Leo, but my question wasn't about *how to use* JavaMail on Tomcat. I already know most of that stuff. My question was, **where is Tomcat 7's JavaMail implementation?** Meaning, is it packaged somewhere inside one of the Tomcat JARs? If so, which JAR? Or is JavaMail both an API and an implementation, and Tomcat just uses it?

Comment: the link I've provided you shows that you have to download the javamail implementation :-) see step #4 "download the java mail API"

Comment: OK, thanks again @Leo (lights are turning on). So to confirm: Tomcat 7 requires JavaMail on the runtime classpath (if you wish to have your WARs send mail). And JavaMail is **both** an API and an implementation. **Correct?** Thanks again!

Comment: Leo is correct.  The JavaMail API can be implemented by other projects, but most people use the JavaMail Reference Implementation.  The GNU project has it's own implementation of the JavaMail API.  The JavaMail spec also allows you to plug in "protocol providers" that do the work of talking to mail servers.  The JavaMail Reference Implementation comes with protocol providers for SMTP, IMAP, and POP3.  See the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) for more details.