# Javamail with Netbeans and Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-mail

I need to use the Javamail api to send emails in my web app (made with Tomcat 8.0.27.0 as server and Netbeans 8.1 as IDE). Since, according to Oracle's documentation, the api should be already present in Java EE, I tried to import `javax.mail.*` or `javax.mail.internet.*` in my servlet but Netbeans couldn't find the packages.

I also tried to add the "Java EE 7 api Library" to the project's libraries, so that Netbeans could find the packages, but then at run time Tomcat returns a ClassNotFound/NoClassDefFound exception about `com.sun.mail.util.PropUtil`.

I searched for a solution but the only answer I found was to download the api and import it as a library in my project, but again shouldn't be it already present in Java EE? Am I missing something?

Comment: Tomcat is not a Java EE server and does not provide its libraries. You need to rethink your deployment.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002170/javamail-api-and-tomcat-7-implementation . Also, you may want to consider switching to the Maven project type as it makes all things related to external dependencies a whole lot more convenient than the Netbeans project type.

Comment: If you want EE runtime, you should use [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/), not the plain [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/). Alternatively, add `mail.jar` to your webapp.